# Vert.x 2 HTTP server on Netty: response bytes are written but never flushed, channel never closed

Tags: netty, vert.x

Using the HTTP server in Vert.x 2.1.6 (based on Netty 4.0.21) to handle HTTP requests, static files are read from the file system and written to the client.
Occasionally, during multiple simultaneous requests (read: rapid clicking in the browser), a random request never gets any response.
E.g. clicking the logout link will trigger requests for background image, a logo, a couple of css files etc.
All files are returned successfully except, say, the logo file, for which the http request just hangs.
The situation does not always occur, but seems to be triggered by not waiting for previous requests to finish before launching new ones.

To try to figure out what is going on, I added LoggingHandlers to the netty pipeline created by the Vert.x DefaultHttpServer.
The example below shows output for a successful and an unsuccessful request for the file logo.png (size 12754B).
The output leaves me with two questions:

1. In the successful example, after writing the 12754 bytes of the actual file, another 12774 + 10 bytes are written. What are those bytes?
2. In the unsuccessful example, there is a FLUSH operation before the WRITE operation, after which no more activity can be seen. Even explicitly closing the response is ignored. What is going on?

*EDIT regarding question 1: I realized the channel is used for multiple HTTP requests, so the trailing bytes are just another file being written.*

The request:

```
GET /authenticate/res/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.12:18443
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://192.168.0.12:18443/authenticate/res/css/login.css
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

Output when successful:

```
$ grep 0xafd76300 /var/log/server.log
2017-09-06 15:17:12,609 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] REGISTERED
2017-09-06 15:17:12,609 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] REGISTERED
2017-09-06 15:17:12,609 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] ACTIVE
2017-09-06 15:17:12,609 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] ACTIVE
2017-09-06 15:17:12,625 [SslHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2017-09-06 15:17:12,625 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] USER_EVENT: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandshakeCompletionEvent@38f7a12a
2017-09-06 15:17:12,625 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] USER_EVENT: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandshakeCompletionEvent@38f7a12a
2017-09-06 15:17:12,629 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] RECEIVED: DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success)
2017-09-06 15:17:12,633 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] RECEIVED(0B)
2017-09-06 15:17:12,634 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] WRITE(12754B)
2017-09-06 15:17:12,634 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] FLUSH
2017-09-06 15:17:12,635 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] WRITE(0B)
2017-09-06 15:17:12,635 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] WRITE(12774B)
2017-09-06 15:17:12,635 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] FLUSH
2017-09-06 15:17:12,636 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] WRITE(0B)
2017-09-06 15:17:12,636 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] FLUSH
2017-09-06 15:17:12,636 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] WRITE(10B)
2017-09-06 15:17:12,636 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] WRITE(0B)
2017-09-06 15:17:12,636 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] FLUSH
2017-09-06 15:17:12,636 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] CLOSE()
2017-09-06 15:17:12,636 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 => /172.16.238.11:8443] CLOSE()
2017-09-06 15:17:12,636 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 :> /172.16.238.11:8443] INACTIVE
2017-09-06 15:17:12,637 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 :> /172.16.238.11:8443] UNREGISTERED
2017-09-06 15:17:12,637 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0xafd76300, /192.168.10.113:60180 :> /172.16.238.11:8443] UNREGISTERED
```

Output when unsuccessful:

```
$ grep 0x09db306c /var/log/server.log
2017-09-06 15:17:25,569 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] REGISTERED
2017-09-06 15:17:25,569 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] REGISTERED
2017-09-06 15:17:25,569 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] ACTIVE
2017-09-06 15:17:25,569 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] ACTIVE
2017-09-06 15:17:25,571 [SslHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2017-09-06 15:17:25,571 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] USER_EVENT: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandshakeCompletionEvent@38f7a12a
2017-09-06 15:17:25,572 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] USER_EVENT: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandshakeCompletionEvent@38f7a12a
2017-09-06 15:17:25,608 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] RECEIVED: DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success)
2017-09-06 15:17:25,608 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] RECEIVED(0B)
2017-09-06 15:17:25,609 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] FLUSH
2017-09-06 15:17:25,610 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] WRITE(12754B)
2017-09-06 15:17:25,610 [LoggingHandler] DEBUG: [id: 0x09db306c, /192.168.10.113:60300 => /172.16.238.11:8443] WRITE(0B)
```

The request handler registered on the HttpServer looks like this:

```
Vertx vertx = ...
HttpServerRequest req = ...
HttpServerResponse response = req.response();
vertx.fileSystem().readFile(file, (AsyncResult<Buffer> e) -> {
    try {
        if (e.succeeded()) {
            Buffer buf = e.result();
            response.putHeader("Content-Type", MimeMapper.getTypeForFile(file)+";charset=UTF-8");
            response.putHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(buf.length()));
            response.write(buf);
            response.end();
            response.close();
            LOG.trace("Write success (%d) %s...", buf.length(), file);
        } else {
           LOG.error("Write failure", e.cause());
        }
    } catch (Exception x) {
        LOG.error("Write failure", x);
    }
});
```

*EDIT: calling `response.close()` have the effect of immediately unregistering and inactivating the channel. Without that call, the unregistration is triggered automatically about 5 minutes after the last write. In the unsuccessful case, unregistration is never triggered, the channel is left in active mode indefinitely.*

I modified the Netty pipeline in Vert.x 2 DefaultHttpServer (version 2.1.6, ssl and compression activated) by adding two LoggingHandlers:

```
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
bootstrap.group(availableWorkers);
bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
tcpHelper.applyConnectionOptions(bootstrap);
tcpHelper.checkSSL(vertx);
bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
      ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
      if (tcpHelper.isSSL()) {
        pipeline.addLast("ssl", tcpHelper.createSslHandler(vertx, false));
      }
      pipeline.addLast("flashpolicy", new FlashPolicyHandler());
      pipeline.addLast("httpDecoder", new HttpRequestDecoder(4096, 8192, 8192, false));
      pipeline.addLast("httpEncoder", new VertxHttpResponseEncoder());
      pipeline.addLast("reqlog", new LoggingHandler());
      if (compressionSupported) {
        pipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpChunkContentCompressor());
      }
      if (tcpHelper.isSSL() || compressionSupported) {
        // only add ChunkedWriteHandler when SSL is enabled otherwise it is not needed as FileRegion is used.
        pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());       // For large file / sendfile support
      }
      pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerHandler());
      pipeline.addLast("rsplog", new LoggingHandler());
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you invoke `response.close()` ? This closes the underlying TCP connection.

Comment: In my original code there is no close. I added `response.close()` just to see if it would force Netty to flush and unregister the channel. It didn't.

Comment: Did you try to upgrade vert.x ? This version is very old, maybe its a bug ?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to work with vert.x 2 for the moment. Thanks for the suggestion though, you are perfectly right. I'm really curious what could make Netty reverse the order of write and flush, since they seems to be executed as a single op with the `WriteAndFlushTask`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems I found the source of the error. To me, it looks like a classic concurrency issue. I fixed it by changing a single line of code in vertx-core version [2.1.6](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/releases/tag/v2.1.6), changing a `write` operation to `writeAndFlush`. The fix is probably bypassing the intentions of the original author and will result in a few un-necessary flush operations on the netty channel.

This is what I think is happening. To follow my reasoning in the code, have a look at `org.vertx.java.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase` in 2.1.6. There are two flags involved: `read` and `needsFlush`. I am assuming here that there are two threads accessing the channel concurrently.

1. Vert.x `HttpServer` receives a http request, opens a Netty channel and successfully reads the entire request. The handler is put in READ mode while reading, then back into WRITE mode, flushing the write buffer: `read = false`, `needsFlush = false`.
2. Before Vertx HttpServer starts to write the response to the first request, it receives another http request and starts to read again. This puts the handler in READ mode: `read = true`
3. The http handler now wants to write the response to the first request, but since `read = true`, the writing will begin by setting `needsFlush = true`, and prepares to queue the response.
4. However, before any bytes are queued, the reading thread takes over again, finishes reading the second request, thus setting `read = false`, flushes the (empty) write buffer (since `needsFlush = true`) and sets `needsFlush = false`.
5. Now the writing thread picks up again. Since it is already past checking the `read` flag, it just writes the bytes to the channel without flushing. The channel will now never be flushed, since no more `endReadAndFlush` will occur.

To fix this problem, I updated

```
org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.VertxHttpHandler.write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise)
```

to do `ctx.writeAndFlush(msg, promise)` instead of just `ctx.write(msg, promise)`.

It is possible that there is something that I overlooked, which would fix the problem without having to patch vertx2. Perhaps it is possible to configure vertx2 to create a new netty channel for each and every http request, instead of reusing the same channel for multiple requests? I'm happy to accept such an alternate solution if anybody can propose one.

EDIT: maybe I should add that I upgraded Netty to 4.0.51 while recompiling Vertx2. The problem was the same on both versions though, perhaps a bit worse after the upgrade.